# C# with HTML AGILITY PACK cannot get value of div class

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

i have to download some data from site but i cannot find proper way.
This is class im interested of:

```
<div class="flex-item text-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="wsgk@wsgk.com.pl">
        <a class="ajax-modal-link icon-envelope cursor-pointer  addax addax-cs_hl_email_submit_click" data-count-hovers="" data-hover-class-remove="addax addax-cs_hl_email_click_submit" data-hover-class-add="addax addax-cs_hl_email_hover" data-ga="l-email-modal" data-type="p" data-tracking-click="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mail-modal" data-company-trade-id="3123" data-company-id="120863029" data-company-email="mail@mail.com" data-company-name="Name" data-ajax-modal-tracking-type="result">
            email
        </a>
    </div>
```

THIS IS MY LOOP:

```
    foreach(var site in website)
    {

        var html = site.Value;
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var _html = web.Load(html); 
        var node = _html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='flex-item text-primary']");
        foreach (var mail in node)
        {
          try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mail.Attributes["data-original-title"].Value);
            }
         

        }

    }
```

**This is output from console:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT32x.png)
Could you please help me out?

// UPDATE

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0 bottom-content">
    <div class="flex-item text-primary">
        <a class="icon-telephone  addax addax-cs_hl_phonenumber_click" href="https://panoramafirm.pl/zachodniopomorskie,gryficki,trzebiatów,kwiatowa,3/pphu_agawa_inz_waldemar_fiolek-scinlt_aal.html" data-count-hovers="" data-hover-class-remove="addax addax-cs_hl_phonenumber_click" data-hover-class-add="addax addax-cs_hl_phone_hover" data-ga="l-phone" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-tracking-click="https://panoramafirm.pl/tr4ck1ng.png?displayType=results&amp;type=clickphone&amp;sid=8f04e98ua6kmfmkr7fe1b26rth&amp;lstPersistentId=120898648_611&amp;page=4" data-tracking-id="120898648_611" data-type="p" data-original-title="601 155 493">
                   telefon
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item text-primary">
        <a class="icon-website  text-secondary  addax addax-cs_hl_hit_homepagelink_click" disabled="disabled">
            www
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item text-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="agawa.fiolek@gmail.com">
        <a class="ajax-modal-link icon-envelope cursor-pointer  addax addax-cs_hl_email_submit_click" data-count-hovers="" data-hover-class-remove="addax addax-cs_hl_email_click_submit" data-hover-class-add="addax addax-cs_hl_email_hover" data-ga="l-email-modal" data-type="p" data-tracking-click="https://panoramafirm.pl/tr4ck1ng.png?displayType=results&amp;type=clickemail&amp;sid=8f04e98ua6kmfmkr7fe1b26rth&amp;lstPersistentId=120898648_611&amp;page=4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mail-modal" data-company-trade-id="611" data-company-id="120898648" data-company-email="agawa.fiolek@gmail.com" data-company-name="Pphu Agawa Inż Waldemar Fiołek" data-ajax-modal-tracking-type="result">
            email
        </a>
    </div>
            <div class="flex-item text-primary">
            <a class="icon-check-point show-on-map
                                     cursor-pointer
                 addax addax-cs_hl_hit_company_footer_map" data-lat="54.05219" data-lon="15.28209" data-tradeid="611" data-companyid="120898648" data-ga="l-map" data-type="p" data-tracking-click="https://panoramafirm.pl/tr4ck1ng.png?displayType=results&amp;type=clickmap&amp;sid=8f04e98ua6kmfmkr7fe1b26rth&amp;lstPersistentId=120898648_611&amp;page=4">
                mapa
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How i can skip 2 first divs and then pick third?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  My guess is that this markup is generated on the client using JS, and as such is not present in the markup when you try to parse it using HTMLAgilityPack.  What is HtmlWeb?

Comment: @HaukurHaf web = {HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb}
I downloaded whole site and i can see this with "view page source" so i can get "into this" :) i need to find way why this isnt working.

Comment: What is the URL of the site?

Comment: I found my problem. There was 4 same classes and my program picked up first one. thanks anyway :)

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack returns `null` when nothing was found in SelectNodes, not an empty list. This causes the foreach to fail

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I updated thread. Could you please check if you can help me?
My problem is:
4 same called classes and my code pick first one, but i want only third.
Its always the same.

Comment: If it is always the third one, adding a `[3]` to that filter may work. And/or a `[@data-original-title]` to filter for divs having that attribute

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Where i should add this?

Comment: After the expression in `SelectNodes("//div[@class='flex-item text-primary']");`, so `SelectNodes("//div[@class='flex-item text-primary'][3]");` etc (but I didn't test this)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing It doesnt work, but i fixed that by myself. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have no need to do a loop just use the array and singlenode:

```
        var node = _html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='flex-item text-primary'][3]");
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["data-original-title"].Value);
```